# pip on Windows giving the error - Unknown or unsupported command 'install'

Tags: python, pip

I installed pip on Windows by downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.0.2.tar.gz#md5=47ec6ff3f6d962696fe08d4c8264ad49 and running `python setup.py install`

Installation went fine with no errors.

But when I tried installing selenium package with it, it gives me the following error -

```
pip install -U selenium
Unknown option: u
Unknown or unsupported command 'install'
```

Where I'm making the mistake?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Do you happen to have the Perl pip lying around somewhere?

Sounds like the problem described here:

https://github.com/mike-perdide/gitbuster/issues/62

To check, in Windows command prompt execute:

```
C:\>where pip
```

This will potentially output the following:

```
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\pip
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\pip.bat
```

If so, this is your problem. Unistall Strawberry Perl or use the full path to python pip.

Comment: This is only pip(Python) installed on my system.

Comment: Sure? Can you provide the output if you type just `pip` on the command line?

Comment: Ahh.. my bad. I has Strawberry Perl already installed. So, that already has a pip associated. I was able to catch this error after running the command on cygwin which showed the error properly. After de-installing Strawberry Perl, I was able to run that command properly. Thanks.

Comment: I had the problem with Strawberry Perl too.  Removing it fixes pip

Comment: In Python.org 2.7 the path is `c:\Python27\Scripts\pip`.

Comment: In my case, I had to install pip first by downloading and executing this [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py). After installation of pip, I followed the steps of this answer and fix my problem.

Comment: I believe that **uninstall** is not really necessary, I have only  to insert Python installation path before Strawberry on my **PATH** environment variable.

Comment: Continuing with @ElvioMartinelli 's comment, I created additional system variables `_PerlPath` `_PyPath`, `_zProgPath`, etc with `_zProgPath` set to e.g. `%_PyPath%;%_PerlPath%;%_AspPath%;%_SQLPath%` and `Path` set to `%_WinPath%;%_JavaPath%;%_zProPath%`. Windows seems to expand environment variables in alphabetical order, which is what's up with the `_`s and `_z` to force evaluation of the first and second layers of variables before `Path`, which is now on the 3rd layer.

Answer (score 19):

This error is because the system is finding pip.bat before it finds pip.exe.

You do NOT need to uninstall Strawberry Perl or type the whole path.

What I do is to simply type pip.exe (same number of keystrokes as apt-get) when I want to use the Python utility.  This method seems to work find for me on Win7 with Python(x,y) 2.7x and Strawberry Perl installed.

Answer (score 13):

Had the same problem under Ubuntu and did:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove pip
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: Thanks for the non-windows answer. Worked for me too, on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem as well, and like Johannes said, it's because the perl pip is interfering with your Python pip.

To get around it, you can simply do this as well:

`python -m pip install <package_name>`

Answer (score 6):

You should provide path in `environment variable` for `pip.exe` file

while executing `install command` you should use below command

```
pip.exe install selenium
```

This will surely work, for me this worked :)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the very helpful nswer of Johannes:
If you don't want to uninstalll Strawberry, you can re-arrange the order of `PATH` entrys in your Windows system to ensure your `Python\Scripts` are found before the strawberry entries. If you don't want to do this manually, you can use tools like the "Rapid Environment Editor".

Answer (score 4):

You can also solve this problem without removing Strawberry Perl or type the whole path.Move to this C:\Python2.7\Scripts(your Python directory) directory,then use pip command.

Answer (score 3):

**For Python 3.X and above:**

In the CMD prompt type:

```
py -m pip install  <package_name>
```

*Make sure pip is installed already.* 
*Setup the environment variable for pip pointing to the exe file*

To upgrade:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with DwimPerl. Uninstalling Dwim fixed the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install -U selenium

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in **windows 10**, finally resolved the problem successfully.

I used the following command
`where pip`

I was showing multiple installations of pip. Once removed other installation it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

open cmd and type where pip and you will have

```
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\pip.bat
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin
C:\Users\athus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe
```

and go to `C:\Dwimperl\perl` and delete `bin` folder.
and again type where pip and you will only have

```
C:\Users\athus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe
```

and enjoy python pip.